# How to get img from API (React/TypeScript)?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, image, api, path

Problem is that i see only icon while file doesn't upload.
Thanks in advance for your help.

```
       import React, { FC } from "react";
       import { IUser } from "../types/Types";
       import App from "../App";
       interface UserItemProps {
        user: IUser;
       }
      const UserItem: FC<UserItemProps> = ({ user }) => {
       return (
        <body>
         <article className="UserPage">
           <h2 className="Title_options ">
           {user.title} <h6 className="Name">{user.name}</h6>
           <h6>{user.address}</h6>
           </h2>
           <img src={user.pictures} />
          </article>
         </body>
        );
       };

       export default UserItem;
```

Types

```
   export interface IUser {
        name: string;
        title: string;
        headers: string;
        id: number;
        email: string;
        address: string | number;
        pictures: string;
     }
```

[API][1]

```
   [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/9uISi.png
```

[How it looks in Chrome][2]

```
   [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/wBaZ8.png
```

Comment: The pictures prop is an array, not a string.

Comment: It says (Type 'String[]' is not assignable to type 'String'.) I change {pictures: Array<String>;}

Comment: Also, your HTML is bad. Remove the body tag. Replace the h2 with span or div.

Comment: it has nothing to do with api

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace this:

```
<img src={user.pictures} />
```

with this:

```
{user.pictures && user.pictures.map(picture => (<img src={picture} />)}
```

Comment: Also, update `IUser ` so that pictures is a `string[]` not `string`